# how to generate dynamic text field?

Tags: javascript, html

How to generate the dynamic text field when we press a button

```
<script>
   functiom click() {
   }
</script>
<body>
   <form name="s">
      <input type="submit" onclick="click()"/>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Please explain in further detail what this dynamic text field does.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean dynamically add text field then you can use something like this:

```
<script>
  functiom click()
{
var field = document.createElement("input");
field.type = "text";
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(field);
 }
</script>
<body>
<form name="s" id="myForm">
<input type="submit" onclick="click()"/>
</form>
```

But still I would recommend to read a Javascript book first.